# Find coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $\left(1−x^7\right) \left(1−x^8\right) \left(1−x^9\right) (1−x)^{-3}$

Tags: combinations, multinomial-theorem

find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in this expansion:
$$
\left(1−x^7\right) \left(1−x^8\right) \left(1−x^9\right) (1−x)^{-3}
$$
Please help me solve this question

Comment: up-voting because as is evident from the comments to the answer, the OP finished the problem by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Expand $(1-x)^{-3}$ into a series, writing
$$
(1-x)^{-3} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$
so you would get
$$
\left(1−x^7\right) \left(1−x^8\right) \left(1−x^9\right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$
and think about how you can get a product of $x^{10}$ from these 4 factors:

- if the first factor is present, you get $-x^7 a_3 x^3$
- if the second factor is present, you get $-x^8 a_2 x^2$
- if the third factor is present, ...
- if on the fourth factor is present, ...

and the result is the final sum of those.

---

**HINT 2**

Alternative way suggested in the comments below: note that 
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 \ldots
$$
so you can write
$$
\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}
 = \frac{1}{1-x} - x^7 \frac{1}{1-x}
 =  1 + x + x^2 \ldots - x^7 - x^8 \ldots
 = 1 + x + \ldots x^6
$$
and your products become
$$
(1+x+\ldots x^6)(1+x+\ldots x^7)(1+x+\ldots x^8)
$$

Comment: Isn't it better to cancel the negative power totally?

Comment: @A.Γ. there are no negative powers in the taylor series

Comment: I am not saying "in the taylor series". I mean to cancel the negative power $(1-x)^{-3}$.

Comment: @A.Γ. that will be hard to do, you have $(1 - 3x - 3x^2 + x^3)^{-1}$, you cannot cancel non-multiplicative powers

Comment: For example, $\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^6$ etc

Comment: @A.Γ. You could, with similar effect. The end result likely to be a bit simpler that way, I agree, but will require a multinomial coefficient, whereas in my way, the arithmetic is much simpler to do

Comment: @gt6989b Thank You, I was able to get to the answer due to the hint. :D

Comment: @user768300 You are welcome. I hope you stay around and contribute to the site.